# Atomic boolean, test for current value

Tags: java, multithreading, atomic

I have problems understanding the AtomicBoolean and how could i make best use of its method getAndSet(boolean newValue);

Volatile makes all changes directly in memory, so if CPU cannot cache some value, visibility of changes is guaranteed between threads. 
Synchronized protects from race conditions.

Is the following code thread safe ? AtomicBoolean.get should provide volatile guarantees, but what about race conditions ?

```
private static AtomicBoolean tokenValid = new AtomicBoolean(false); 
   //....

    public non-synchronized method() { 

    if (token == null || tokenValid.getAndSet(tokenValid.get()) == false) 

           token = createNewToken()

 }
```

I understand there are many resources regarding the Atomic classes however i haven't found an example as this, which might be indication that i am misusing AtomicBoolean.

Comment: It's hard to say whether or not it's safe when we don't know what you're trying to achieve. If you're just trying to get the current value, what's wrong with `tokenValid.get()`?

Comment: I don't think that code is logic-safe. What are you trying to achieve with it?

Comment: what happens if i try to do tokenValid.get and some other thread tries to execute set ? What i want to d:, if condition above is not satified, get some new token. More then one thread can test at the same time if condition is satisfied and i want to get token only once

Comment: What is `token` and why are you checking if it is `null`? Do you understand what the concurrency problem is and why `getAndSet()` is supposed to protect against it?

Comment: token is some String representation of a value i get from some service and it can be null on server startup, It should be fetched only when it required first time.

Comment: Neither `synchronized` nor `AtomicXxx` can magically shield you from race conditions. Be careful to never confuse a *data race* for a much more general and dangerous *race condition*. Data race is but one of many types of race conditions your code may suffer from.

Comment: Furthermore, reasoning about the semantics of `volatile` in the simplistic terms of "cache flush/invalidation" will not give you correct insight into the Java Memory Model. These are not viable shortcuts to the comprehension of the *happens before* concept.

Comment: so, if we put aside token object for a moment and i rewrite the following such as the: if (!tokenValid.getAndSet(true) ) would this ensure that two threads do not trigger createNewToken procedure ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Your code is not thread-safe. The `AtomicBoolean` methods themselves are thread-safe and avoid race conditions, but between the calls to those methods there can still be other threads accessing the object. In your case, first `tokenValid.get()` is called, and then `tokenValid.getAndSet(boolean)` is called. Between those two calls other threads might call one of `tokenValid`'s methods.

Not to mention that you also access the `token` variable, and it is not clear whether that is a member variable (which might be accessible to other threads) or a local variable (which isn't).

Comment: So, if i did tokenValid.getAndSet(true) then it would be thread safe ? Put aside token object for a moment.

Comment: @user3360241. Just with respect to `tokenValid`, yes. If another thread executes `tokenValid.getAndSet(true)`, then in one of the threads `true` will be returned, and in the other the old value of `tokenValid`. It cannot occur that both threads see the old value and then both set the value to true.